# What is the default dictionary?

Tags: package-management

What is the default dictionary that provides spell check for programs, like empathy and Libreoffice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That package is `libenchant1c2a`.

[image: im2]

As you can see from the package it is named `enchant` and uses `ispell`, `aspell` and `myspell` as a backend.

And the files are stored in `~/.config/enchant`.